# port forward with openVPN to access local machine remotely

Tags: linux, openvpn, port-forwarding, aws

I have an OpenVPN server set up on my AWS Linux instance and I can successfully use the OpenVPN client to connect to the server using an `.ovpn` configuration file. My question is how can I set up port forwarding to access web servers hosted on my local machine using `myAwsPublicIp:openedPort` without having to set up forwarding rules on my router. I already tried opening the port on my AWS firewall rules but that didn't do it. How does portmap.io achieve this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `tried opening the port` ... did you try *forwarding* the port? What did you actually do? be as detailed as possible, perhaps you did it wrong

Answer (score 1):

[This blog](https://juliansimioni.com/blog/howto-access-a-linux-machine-behind-a-home-router-with-ssh-tunnels/) explains how to do it.

You run the following command from the local machine, to connect to the vpn host:

```
ssh -R 10022:localhost:22 HostA
```

where `HostA` is the VPN that is globally accessible. Then you can ssh into the local machine by first connectint to VPN, then running

```
ssh -P youruser@localhost
```